# How does the synchronized keyword function in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am curious to know how the synchronized keyword actually functions in java , I have the following code snippet lets say -:

```
synchronized(lockObject){
// some activity
}
```

if the synchronized statement is not able to obtain the lock will it try again or should I put it in a while loop, it would be great if you can explain as to why it happens.

What is the difference between

```
synchronized(lockObject){
}
```

and

```
while(true){
synchronized(lock_object){
break;
}
}
```

Comment: It blocks until it gets notified and can acquire the monitor. There should be plenty of related questions and answers on SO.

Comment: but this statement synchronized(lockObject) will only execute once I suppose, if its not able to acquire the lock it will not run any of the statements in its block am I true?

Comment: If it's not able to acquire the lock, it will wait forever.

Comment: There is no difference between the last two pieces of code => you would use the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually no difference. The synchronized block will wait until the lock is available if the lock isn't already available. There's no need to loop.

Comment: what is the difference between synchronized(lockObject) and while(true){synchronized(lockObject)} then

Comment: There has to be something in braces after the synchronized block.

Comment: may be I should reframe the question